# How to number values in string array with int

Tags: c#

I have some strings in string array.
Now I wanna to give before first string prefix 1: string..etc

Example:

```
Test
Test
Test
```

Expected result:

```
1. Test
2. Test
3. Test
```

Is that even possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, what you have tried?

Comment: You can enumerate the index and add to string

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I just asked because I dont know how to do it ..

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes I know I must enumerate it ..But how to add it into the string?

Comment: `string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array.Select((item, i) => $"{i + 1}. {item}"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in-place with an array of strings (without creating a new array), you can't use Linq. Instead, just use something like this:

```
public static void AddNumberingPrefix(string[] strings)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    {
        strings[i] = $"{i+1}. {strings[i]}";
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
string[] items = {"First", "Second", "Third"};
AddNumberingPrefix(items);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", items));
```

This outputs:

> 1. First
> 2. Second
> 3. Third

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) (Linq) with Index, and use string formatting to include Index as prefix of string.

For Example

```
var result = strCollection.Select((x,index)=> $"{index+1}.{x}");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of LINQ `Select` that gives you the index:

```
yourList.Select((el, idx) => $"{idx+1}. {el}");
```